# Some Question About Polling

Tags: linux

I'm trying to understand the section
*[13.2.1 polling[https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/13_IOSystems.html]](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/13_IOSystems.html)*

I don't understand two parts in the link:

1. Is that the *["]4. The **control register** ... [."]*, which is mentioned above the *Figure 13.2*, the same as *["]3. The host sets the command ready bit in the **command register** to ...[."]*?
2. *["]2. The host writes a byte of data into the **data-out** register, and ...[."]* Why it's not *data-in* register?

How does Linux do *Polling*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It seems the author has some particular device in mind, probably the parallel port, when writing this sentence, but doesn't mention it, so it sounds like it is a general description of device registers. You shouldn't worry about it, because as a general description it is useless.

The control register and command register is probably the same here.

2. It's data-out because this section talks about sending data. It should have mentioned that somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, and ridiculously I cannot upvote your answer.

Comment: About your/mine 2. is that data-*out* on the perspective of CPU, which sending its data out *to* the disk?

Comment: Yes, it's data-out on the perspective of CPU. Also control and status is from perspective of CPU. As mentioned, the detail fit better for a parallel port than for output to disk. Doing output to disk would be much too slow. Even output to parallel port is not that complicated with modern ports.